# How to convert generated digital sound to analog

Tags: .net

I have developed sound generator program in C# using directsound. It plays perfectly well when any frequency and intensity (dbLevel) is given. My problem is that for example if I want to generate the sound  of Fan or ship but that sound seems very different from the actual analog sound which we hear normally. How can I convert that digital sound to real analog audio. or any other such utility is available???????

Comment: from what you have described, it is highly doubtful you will achieve what you are looking for by converting your synthesized sounds from digital to analog; if done correctly both will sound exactly the same

Answer (score 0):

Play your sound with one application and record the output with a recording application (I've used Free Sound Recorder http://www.sound-recorder.biz/freesoundrecorder.html).

You can't simply convert it, you must play it to render the analog signal.

Answer (score 0):

You are, i presume, writing a tone generator that creates a sine wave / other wave form.

Your sound is digital when you generate it, and the sound card converts it to analogue before it is played by your speaker. All sound is like that, mp3 music, ship sounds, and even your bleeps you made. It is stored digitally on your computer, and converted to analogue each time you play it.

So your question is, what is different about 'natural noises' or 'natural instruments'?

Well, it's just that they have much more complex spectrum. A natural sound is made up of thousands of frequencies mixed together. To generate a natural sound requires analysing the particular sound you want. To do this, you can use a spectrum analyser application, or fourier analysis. Then you will have to generate it.

Or much simpler, just read a recorded wav file, and play it!